# How to create password protected database in visual studio?

Tags: database, visual-studio, password-protection

I want to set password on `.mdf` file that I created in Visual Studio.

What is its procedure? What will be its connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Create the database in Microsoft Access first. Use datasets if you have to work with databases directly in visual studio. This will make your databases more easy to manage via Access. You can password protect Access databases via File menu. About connection strings, sorry I don't know what you would do here :(

Answer (score 0):

To set password you have to go to te Server Explorer > Right Click on your database > select Modify Connection.
In Log on to the server section select 'Use SQL Serer Authentication' option and insert your user name and password.